# What does 'touch' mean in "It opened at a touch"?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

Clay promptly withdrew again and hurried across to the window. It opened at ***a*** ***touch*** and gave on to a wide courtyard.

Comment: The window opened very easily. Clay needed barely to touch it, and it opened.

Comment: He opened the window by touching it.

Comment: Even more interesting is "gave onto".

Answer (score 4):

The window opened **very easily**. Clay needed barely **to touch** it, and it opened.

The meaning is most likely not literal. Clay might've made a more comprehensive movement than just a single touch to open the window; but that is irrelevant for this narrative; the author needed to stress the fact that it opened easily.

From the grammar standpoint, **touch** is a noun, a singular countable noun, as evidenced by the use of the indefinite article **a**.  "The window opened **at one touch**", or "**at a single touch**".

---

Compare with the expression **at a glance**:

> **[At a glance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/at_a_glance)**: (idiomatic) Upon cursory examination; an abbreviated review. "*At a glance it seems that he is a nice guy, but upon digging deeper the truth emerges.*"

Answer (score 3):

The word **touch** is a very common word used as a verb or noun.

In the sentence presented, it's a countable noun that means a light movement or placement of a part of your body, specially your hand  on the window.

The window opened only on a light movement of a part of your body, most probably  your hand, and it provided a view of a wide courtyard.